# How can I check at compile-time whether compiler support C++11 override keyword?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, standards-compliance

How can I check at compile-time whether compiler support C++11 `override` keyword? Maybe **boost** or something like this?

Comment: Nit-pick: `override` is not a keyword.

Comment: @Snps I'd point out that the accepted solution on that question does not work for `[[override]]` since Boost doesn't support it. So closing this question as a duplicate is a bad idea, IMO.

Comment: The second most popular answer (`__cplusplus`) should work though, shouldn't it? A quote from a comment: "C++11 sets the value of __cplusplus to 201103L. That asserts full conformance to the 2011 standard;" This might not catch browsers that support override but not the complete c++11 standard though. And it wouldn't be pretty and not worth it for `override` in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward way does not exist. There are two ways:

1. Use good old [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Running-the-Compiler) or corresponding functionality in your other build system. [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3atry_compile) has one and, so does [scons](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x4307.html) and any other system.
2. Meticulously check for the compiler versions known to support the features. Fortunately the list of compilers recently shrunk to 3 (clang, gcc and msc++) and [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) maintainers have [done some of the work](http://www.boost.org/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__11_features_not_supported) (it seems they didn't care about the `override` feature).

Comment: As far as I can see, boost doesn't have the appropriate macro to check override support